# Adding WHERE clause of third table in MySQL whose ID is present in first two Inner joined tables

Tags: mysql

I have the following query, where count of two tables is divided and further other column values are displayed.

Both the tables are joined via Months/ year.

```
  select 
        (a.count_one / b.count_two) as final_count, a.orders,
        a.Months, b.Sum
    from 
        (
            select count(*) as count_one, DATE_FORMAT(`date`, "%M %Y") AS `Months`, orders 
            from first_table
            GROUP BY Months)
        ) a
    INNER JOIN
        (
            select count(*) as count_two, DATE_FORMAT(`date`, "%M %Y") AS `Months`, sum(a) AS Sum
            from second_table
            GROUP BY Months)
        ) b
    ON a.Months = b.Months
```

Output:

```
**Month and Year**    **Final_Count**
January 2016              126
February 2016             123
March 2016                 45
....                      ....
...                       ....
...                       ....

What is required?
```

A third table is present, whose keys are in first_Table and second_table. I need to put a WHERE clause, based on third table, that is, WHERE thirdtable.name='Any name'

So, wherever the ID related to the thirdtable.name appears, those results should display, but I am unable to achieve this.

**What I tried?**

I tried a third INNER join AS:

```
INNER JOIN third_table ON a.shid= third_table.id WHERE thirdtable.name='Any name'
```

But, no results are displayed in this case.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subqueries don't select the `id` column, so there's no `a.shid` to compare with. And since the subqueries are grouped by month, you can't select the `id` column in them.

You need to join with the third table in the subqueries.

```
select 
    (a.count_one / b.count_two) as final_count, a.orders,
    a.Months, b.Sum
from 
    (
        select count(*) as count_one, DATE_FORMAT(`date`, "%M %Y") AS `Months`, orders 
        from first_table
        JOIN third_table ON first_table.shid = third_table.id
        WHERE third_table.name = 'Any name'
        GROUP BY Months)
    ) a
INNER JOIN
    (
        select count(*) as count_two, DATE_FORMAT(`date`, "%M %Y") AS `Months`, sum(a) AS Sum
        from second_table
        JOIN third_table ON second_table.shid = third_table.id
        WHERE third_table.name = 'Any name'
        GROUP BY Months)
    ) b
ON a.Months = b.Months
```